# "No" selection takes me to the wrong next msgbox input

Tags: ms-access, msgbox

```
If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you have Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHBB), such as Blue Cross Blue Shield?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
End If
If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to terminate/suspend your Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHB) while on orders?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
    FEHBCancel = InputBox("Please initial here to cancel/suspend your FEHB.")
Else
NoFEHB = InputBox("Please initial here indicating that you do not have Federal Employee Health Benefits.")
End If
```

Above seemed to run through, but the problem I'm running into now is when I ask the first msgbox "Do you have FEHB..." if I select "No", I want it to move on to a new msgbox "please initial here indicating that you do not have...". If the answer is "YES", then I'd like to it go to msgbox "do you want to terminate", another Yes/No msgbox. And from there, potentially another box if they select "no" they don't want to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some VBA code that shows how this should be done. When doing this sort of thing, it often helps to draw out on a piece of paper the logic process, and when coding the If statements, always indent each nested level to maintain readability.

```
Sub sMsg()
    Dim strTerminate As String, strPayFor As String, strNoFEHBB As String
    If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you have FEHBB?", vbYesNo) Then
        If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you want to terminate", vbYesNo) Then
            strTerminate=InputBox("Please initial to terminate")        
        Else    '   No they don't want to terminate
            strPayFor=InputBox("Please initial to pay")
        End If
    Else    ' do not have FEHBB
        strNoFEHBB = InputBox("Please initial here")
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: thank you - so I guess my question is then, after every "If" statement, I should have and "End If" function?

Comment: You can do a simple `If 1=1 Then MsgBox()` all on one line without needing the `End If`. As soon as the action to be taken after the `If` has been evaluated is on a new line, then you do need the matching `End If`. And by indenting the `If`/`Else`/`End If` the same amount it makes it a lot easier to tell when they're not matching.

Comment: So I guess I only have one part and then it'll actually work, thank you for helping my think about this one.

Comment: thank you for helping my think about this one. I get all the way to the "would you like to terminate" statement, but cannot get an inputbox to pop-up if the user selects "no"

If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you have FEHB", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
    If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to cx", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
        If vbYes = InputBox("Please initial here to cancel/suspend your FEHB.") Then
            Else
                PayForFEHB = InputBox("Please initial here...")
        End If
    End If
Else 
    NoFEHB = InputBox("Please initial here that you do not have.")
End If

Comment: I've changed my answer to place the InputBox in the location that I think that you want it to be.